# How ListenTo event is working in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I created two models names are 'Sidebar','listenTestClass'.I created attribute `color1` in `Sidebar` model simillarly I created `c` attribute in `listenTestClass` model.

```
//listenTestClass model
var listenTestClass=Backbone.Model.extend(
                {
                    test:function(value){
                        this.set({c:value});
                    }                       
                }
            );
        var listenTestClassObject=new listenTestClass();
 //sidebar model
 var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
                promptColor:function() {
                    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
                    this.set({color1: cssColor});
                }
        });
var sidebar = new Sidebar();
 //if color1 attribte change,it triggers the following code
 sidebar.on("change:color1", function(model, color2) {
            $('#body1').css({background: color2})
        });
//assigning white color to my body tag.
sidebar.set({color1:'white'}); 
//assigning some random value to "c" attribute
listenTestClassObject.test("hi");
```

object `sidebar` listens to Attribute "C".That means Whenever attribute "C" value changes I want to apply background colour of  is `green`. For this I used the `listenTo` event but it's not working.

```
sidebar.listenTo(listenTestClassObject,"change:c",function(model,c1){sidebar.set({color1:'green'})});
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Works fine, what are you doing differently than http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QQ7jX/ ?

Comment: @muistooshort previous problem getting in `css` file not belongs to `backbone.js`.Thanks for your suggestion.It's working great.Sorry I can't able to like your comment because don'y have reputations.